# vacuum pack of a substance/substrates

Tags: spectroscopy

What equipment can I put a substance or substrate under vacuum pack?

After buying this SERS silver substrates (which can rapidly decay in air). I need to immediately put them in vacuum packaging or container. How do I do that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The most artisanal way to do it would be having a box filled with, at least, nitrogen. Or slowly flushing it continuously. A dessicator can be already around. And a vacuum pump.

Comment: I need something not dangerous. How do you wrap them with vacuum packaging? What instrument is used to create the vacuum package in the 2nd picture?

Comment: @Jtl These are vacuum pouches, which are, for example, used in food industry, too ([example](https://www.meatprocessingproducts.com/vacuum-sealers-vacuum-sealer-bags---rolls.html?siteID=a1LgFw09t88-JuDkzkn2MsoTufKppMZTPA&LSNSUBSITE=Omitted_a1LgFw09t88&utm_source=Linkshare&utm_medium=CPA&utm_campaign=a1LgFw09t88)).  The sealers don't need to be big ([example](https://www.amazon.com/Entrige-Machine-Automatic-Indicator-Stainless/dp/B083BJ5TR1/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1MQGNB7KEHIMM&dchild=1&keywords=vacuum+sealer+machine&qid=1606300647&sprefix=vacuum+sealer%2Caps%2C304&sr=8-1)).

Comment: Flushing said box (`@Alchimista`'s comment) with argon instead of nitrogen could be better because different to nitrogen, argon is more dense than air and thus creates a blanket above the items in the box.  It is a bit more expensive per litre, though.

Comment: @Buttonwood of course. I said at least. But anyway the box seems not to be the desired storage. OP want to pack them. S/he need a sealer or some workaround. There are even box for food which might help.

Comment: These are meant to be used all 5 pcs at once. https://www.oceaninsight.com/products/sampling-accessories/raman/sers/  but I need only one at a time. So if I repack them briefly, would the exposure to oxygen when unpacking them degrade them? By how much? see also https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215649986_SERS_Not_To_Be_Taken_for_Granted_in_the_Presence_of_Oxygen

Comment: @Jtl Maybe an other group at your uni (e.g., inorganic chemistry, catalysis) has a [glovebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glovebox) providing a dry and inert intermediate storage for the set of five samples at room temperature.  (There gloveboxes with a freezer, too; but less frequently seen.)  From there, they either could handout one of the slides at a time when needed, or repackage them in samples of one piece in small pouches, too.

Comment: It's for home use. I graduated from the university dozens of years ago and no access to one now. So it has to be something to be done at home. So if I repack the 5 substrates into individual vacuum sealer. Would the brief transfer exposed them to oxygen and degrade them? Or not?

Comment: What guys? please tell me. If I buy the 5 silver substrates and transfer them immediate to vacuum package using vacuum sealer. It won't degrade the substrate right? I'm learning SERS from home. Catching up with molecular science. Thanks.

Comment: @Jtl Sealing the samples under vacuum both quickly and efficiently (perhaps sample in a vacuum sealed pouch, which in turn again is inside a vacuum sealed pouch) will increase the chances your samples survive.  Perhaps recording a reference spectrum of a pristine sample allows you to recognize if subsequent samples are still good enough after months of storage.  (Possibly the chemical vendor may provide some hints, too.) This may buy you time to keep them outside a glove box (https://www.erowid.org/archive/rhodium/chemistry/equipment/glovebox.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nJ1FKZNQVA).